# Dropdown select list won't display items with custom forms of Zurb Foundation 4 and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I've been having this annoying problem in which I click over a select dropdown input of my custom form, styled with Zurb Foundation 4 in my Rails application, and the list won't show its elements.

I thought at a start that was a problem with simple form, but I changed the f.association for f.collection_select, my code looks like this:

```
<h2><%= I18n.t(".sign_up") %></h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :html => {:class => "custom"}, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <%= f.input :rut %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :supplier_type_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :supplier_type_id, SupplierType.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.error :base %>
  <%= f.submit I18n.t(".sign_up"), :class => "button"  %>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

The most strange thing is that sometimes I'm able to see the items when refreshing the page, but when I get to the page navigating from other view of the app then it won't work. I've also noticed this when using hints for forms (i.e: If I have two hints in the same form, in different inputs, only one would show, but the same one message displays in both inputs when each message should show in their respective input. When reloading the page sometimes it shows one hint, and sometimes the other)

The styling looks good, so I think that it might be a foundation javascript problem.

Another thing I've noticed is that when I load the page the styling does a kind of "blinking" when using custom forms. This blinking it looks likes foundation takes a while to load the styling, I've also noticed this on their own [custom form documentation site](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/custom-forms.html). This may indicate that is a form styled with javascript events or something similar, so this might mean that javascript is working well.

In addition, the checkboxes are having a similar problem, they only can be checked just when you reload the page, it might have some relation with [this problem](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1971).

I'm very lost, some help would become very handy. Thanks!

--edit: Foundation 5 doesn't include custom forms and works better--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some Nick Reed insights I found out that the foundation gem was initializing foundation in application.js like this:

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });

So I checked the docs and I used this:

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

After the "/body" tag in the application layout and everything seems to be working like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You might need to refresh dropdowns on each `page:change` event. Try something like this:

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {
  // SELECTOR_TO_CUSTOM_DROPDOWNS should select any Zurb custom dropdowns you
  // are using.
  $(SELECTOR_TO_CUSTOM_DROPDOWNS).trigger("change");
});
```

That's from the documentation on [Zurb custom form JS](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/custom-forms.html#js).

Comment: Thanks! But I just found a solution. I'm posting it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is caused by turbolinks. It stops `$(document).ready` from firing on page load, which is required by foundation's custom forms.

Using ssorallen's answer and to be more unobtrusive than the OPs, add this to application.js:

```
$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });

$(document).on("page:change", function() {
  if ($('form.custom').length > 0) {
    $(document).foundation('forms');
  }
});
```

Also, if you have jquery/coffeescript that relies on document ready being fired, add [jquery turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) to your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I just figured out that I have repeated asset load on my browser. This is causing a javascript error. It appears that deleting in the manifest

```
//= require turbolinks
```

Solves the problem.

I solved my multiple asset problem changing

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

To the head in my application layout.

After watching the [turbolinks railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks?autoplay=true) I noticed that besides my multiple asset loading, turbolinks and foundation 4 may not be compatible, it might be a solution on [this post](http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2013/06/28/troubleshooting-turbolinks-with-rails-4/). But still doesn't work perfect for me.

I also noticed that navbar is also affected by turbolinks.

I think that this is rather a turbolinks problem and not an specific foundation dropdown. I will close this question and open a new on turbolinks and foundation.